# Haproxy health check permission denied

Tags: linux, haproxy

I am unable to add a backend server because the health check fails with log message

> Health check for server mule/muleapp failed, reason: Layer4 connection
>   problem, info: "General socket error (Permission denied)", check
>   duration: 0ms, status: 0/2 DOWN.

I am however able to telnet into the same IP and host. And adding other backends works. I do not see what permission issue is. My configuration is very simplistic

```
backend mule
    balance     roundrobin
    server      muleapp x.x.x.x:64006 check
```

(substitute x with any number). I am running in HTTP mode. It should be noted that connecting to a local TCPMon port also does not work - but then there is not health check log statements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is SELinux only allowing the web server to make outbound connections to a limited set of ports.

Fixed by doing:

`semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 8001`

after installing semanage with

`yum install policycoreutils-python`

Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/654599/weird-interaction-with-systemctl-with-haproxy-on-centos-7

Answer (score 16):

With SELinux you can easily allow haproxy to connect to any remote backend port:

```
getsebool haproxy_connect_any   # by default 0
setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any 1
```

This works immediately without haproxy restart.